# Bootstrapper line in App.xaml

Tags: caliburn.micro

issue is with the bootstrapper in the App.xaml, still have squiggly stating "unable able to determinte application identity of the caller", yet I am trapping for designtime something else doesn't seem right even though app runs in Debug but it will not run in release mode. Any ideas?

Comment: Show you bootstrapper code. App.xaml might be a good one to share too. Without code it's tough to answer your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

got it now, it was a dependency so deep that it required me to read the inner exception on the failure. Was related to Azure mobile services :(